# Chrome Extension to copy request to C# httpclient code

Tags: chrome

Like chrome network request copy fetch, cURL etc.
[image: screenshot of Chrome showing context menu with many copy commands]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Chrome but if you are open to alternatives, [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) has the ability to [Generate Code Snippets](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/) that achieve the same behavior. It generate the equivalent C# code for http requests, it uses [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) as the HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) with this [Request to Code](https://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code) Add-On that generates code for the selected request in to the language you want (C#, VB .NET or Python).

Edit: Its not a chrome extension but would get the job done.